# How to search for a value in two different type of field or index or heading of mongodb using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I am new to any kind of programming. This is an issue I encountered when using mongodb. Below is the collection structure of the document I imported from two different csv files.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc4217ed94f9d5fe6a350c"
    },
    "Telephone Number": "8429950810",
    "Date of Birth": "01/01/1945"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc4217ed94f9d5fe6a350c"
    },
    "Telephone Number": "8129437810",
    "Date of Birth": "01/01/1998"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bd98d36cc90a9109ab253c"
    },
    "TELEPHONE_NUMBER": "9767022829",
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "16-Jun-98"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bd98d36cc9090109ab253c"
    },
    "TELEPHONE_NUMBER": "9567085829",
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "16-Jan-91"
}
```

The first two entries are from a csv and the next two entries from another csv file. Now I am creating a user interface where users can search for a telephone number. How to write the query to search the telephone number value in both the index ( Telephone Number and TELEPHONE_NUMBER) using find() in the above case. If not possible is there a way to change the index's to a desired format while importing csv to db. Or is there a way where I create two different collection and then import csv to each collections and then perform a collective search of both the collections. Or can we create a compound index and then search the compound index instead. I am using pymongo for all the operations.

Thankyou.

Comment: I'm curious how you managed to get a CSV file to import the field names differently for different rows.

Comment: This happened when I imported two different csv files with different rows into a same collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use or query if different key is used to store same type of data.

```
yourmongocoll.find({"$or":[ {"Telephone Number":"8429950810"}, {"TELEPHONE_NUMBER":8429950810}]})
```

Comment: Thankyou that was helpful. But the execution time will be huge when we will be dealing with millions of data's. Here can we create a compound index and then search the compound index instead.

Comment: You can also create [partial index] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) for both the fields differently . since both keys are at same level and you will be using or query for find. partial index  can be created like this `db.yourcollection.createIndex(
   { Telephone Number: 1},
   { partialFilterExpression: { Telephone Number: { $exists: true } } }
)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your connection string to connect via pymongo. Then the following is an example of how to query for the telephone number "8429950810":

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("connection_string")
db = client["db"]
collection = db["collection"]
results = collection.find({"Telephone Number":"8429950810"})
```

Please note this will return as type cursor, if you would like your documents in a list consider wrapping the query in list() like so:

```
results = list(collection.find({"Telephone Number":"8429950810"}))
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But here I want the users to search for any number in db. In your case it only searches the Telephone Number but not the TELEPHONE_NUMBER index.